# Django Admin change page: How can I put the save button set on the left, and delete button on the right?

Tags: django, django-admin

Currently, I have the default setting.

[image]

How can I switch the positions of the save button sets and delete button while not affecting the mobile css layout (which I like to remain as itself)? What is the best way doing it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `templates/admin/base_site.html`,

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/admin/base.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

In `static/css/admin/base.css`,

```
.submit-row p.deletelink-box {
    float: right;
}

.submit-row [type=submit] {
    float: left !important;
}

.submit-row [name=_save] {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Then we will have
[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Flip back to Save Button on the Right for Django 4.2.x+

For anyone looking to do the opposite of this (since Django updated the sides of Delete and Save by default in 4.2.x+) you can do the following:

Update `templates/admin/base_site.html` and add these lines:

```
    .submit-row{
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    .submit-row a.deletelink {
        margin-left: unset !important;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

This will flip set the `Delete` back on the Left and the `Save` on the right again

[Screenshot in 4.2.2 after adding this CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATNCt.png)